# Question about properties of Picard-Lindeloef existence theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a few questions about solutions that arise from differential equations where Picard-Lindeloef can be applied:

1. In the problem $y'=f(t,y)=-y^2$, solutions have the form $\frac{1}{x-c}$ and always have a discontinuity point, what is causing this? Is it that $f(t,y)$ has a zero for some value of $y$? Will this always happen?
2. If a structure funciton $f$ is locally Lipschitz on an entire interval, do the unique solutions always exist on that entire interval? I don't mean globally Lipschitz, I mean locally Lipschitz on an interval such as $[0,1)$, for example $f(t,y)=\frac{1}{y-1}$
3. What about $y'=\arctan(y)$, this is globally Lipschitz but also has a zero, do the solutions have a discontinuity point? (I don't think this is analytically solvable, but I'm guessing it can still be analyzed using numerical methods)

Comment: For (1): This doesn't actually answer your question, but the size of the neighborhood around the initial point that's guaranteed by Picard-Lindeloef depends on the Lipschitz constant for $f$. The function $y^2$ is not Lipschitz on the whole real line (that is, it's not $K$-Lipschitz on the entire real line for any fixed $K$), so you wind up with a small interval, and in this case it doesn't continue beyond it.

Answer (score 2):

$f(t,y)$ having a zero doesn't have much to do with whether the solution has a discontinuity (except that if there is $y_0$ such that $f(t,y_0) = 0$ for all $t$ then the constant $y = y_0$ is a solution, which of course is continuous on all of $\mathbb R$).

If the differential equation is linear, i.e. $f(t,y) = a(t) y + b(t)$ for some continuous functions $a(t)$ and $b(t)$, then all solutions are defined on all of $\mathbb R$.  For differential equations that may not be linear but where $f(t,y)$ is bounded by a function linear in $y$, we can bound the solutions using  Grönwall's inequality, so it can't go to $\infty$ in finite time.  This applies, for example, to your $y' = \arctan(y)$, so the solutions of that equation are continuous on all of $\mathbb R$.